# Multiple results on outer query of correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I was wondering if it is possible to have the inner query return multiple results that are then queried by the outer query?

Here is a reproducible example:

In this example, I'd like to know the name and salary of the highest paid employee of each department.

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
    WORKER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(25),
    LAST_NAME CHAR(25),
    SALARY INT(15),
    JOINING_DATE DATETIME,
    DEPARTMENT CHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO Worker 
    (WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) VALUES
        (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (002, 'Niharika', 'Verma', 80000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (003, 'Vishal', 'Singhal', 300000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (004, 'Amitabh', 'Singh', 500000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (005, 'Vivek', 'Bhati', 500000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (006, 'Vipul', 'Diwan', 200000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (007, 'Satish', 'Kumar', 75000, '14-01-20 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (008, 'Geetika', 'Chauhan', 90000, '14-04-11 09.00.00', 'Admin');
```

Finding the highest salary of each department is easy enough:

```
SELECT MAX(SALARY), DEPARTMENT
FROM Worker
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT;
```

But how do I also add the names of the employees who earn these salaries to the results?

Many thanks!

Comment: You should store department id in the table, foreign key to the departments table.

Comment: Why do you specifically mention a correlated subquery in the title?

Comment: @GordonLinoff is that not what this is? Happy to change it, if not.

Comment: @jarlh ok, so it would be a problem with the set up of the table (which I didn't do myself), and not a question of me improperly querying the data?

Comment: @seabass20 . . . There are many ways to approach this.  A correlated subquery is only one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your query with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Worker
WHERE (DEPARTMENT, SALARY) IN (
  SELECT DEPARTMENT, MAX(SALARY) 
  FROM Worker
  GROUP BY DEPARTMENT 
);
```

or if you are using MySql 8.0+ with `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT w.* 
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY SALARY DESC) rnk
  FROM Worker
) w
WHERE w.rnk = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a361e2396b645edcbe484890b5e4047).
Results:

```
> WORKER_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SALARY | JOINING_DATE        | DEPARTMENT
> --------: | :--------- | :-------- | -----: | :------------------ | :---------
>         3 | Vishal     | Singhal   | 300000 | 2014-02-20 09:00:00 | HR        
>         4 | Amitabh    | Singh     | 500000 | 2014-02-20 09:00:00 | Admin     
>         5 | Vivek      | Bhati     | 500000 | 2014-06-11 09:00:00 | Admin     
>         6 | Vipul      | Diwan     | 200000 | 2014-06-11 09:00:00 | Account
```

Comment: Hi @forpas. I think the MySQL 8.0 version is what I'm looking for, the other answer doesn't quite work (I think), though. In the first answer, wouldn't it be possible for for an employee from one department (let's say she is the second best paid employee in her department) to have the same salary as the highest paid employee of another department. In that scenario, she would still show up, right?

Comment: Both answers work fine. The answer for your question is no, because the comparison is made for **both** DEPARTMENT and SALARY. So *she is the second best paid employee in her department* the comparison will return FALSE because either the DEPARTMENT or the SALARY will not match. Of course window functions offer better performance and if your version of MySql is 8.0+ you should use the 2nd query.

Comment: great. I originally had that as my solution, but didn't realize it would work that way. Thanks for the help!